# Cant get an 'IF(OR(AND' formula to work in Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

I just can't seem to get this to work right. I believe the 'COUNT' end parenthesis is where I'm messing up, but I only started learning excel formulas tonight, so I'm totally stuck. Can anyone see whats wrong with this?

=IF(OR(AND(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},F4))>0), (COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},I4))=0)), AND(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},I4))>0), (COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},F4))=0), F4+I4+1, 0)

Here's the logic I'm aiming for: **IF** F4 contains a number **AND** I4 does not **OR** **IF** I4 contains a number and F4 does **NOT** than display 0 inside of the cell containing this formula, otherwise **ADD** F4 and I4 and 1 together and display them inside of the cell containing this formula.

(SHWEEW! What a mouth full :X)
Thank you in advance, everyone!

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem, but maybe you are looking for `=IFERROR(F4+I4+1,0)`.

Comment: This is useful, also. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced parentheses and mixed up true and false outputs. Heres an edited version:

```
=IF(OR(AND(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},F4))>0, (COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},I4))=0)), AND(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},I4))>0, (COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},F4))=0))),  0, F4+I4+1)
```

However, this could still generate errors if your conditions are not met and cells F4 or I4 contain characters aside from numbers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `find()`.  Instead try the function `isnumber()`.

Assuming the logic you're aiming for is complete (ie, I haven't misinterpereted), this formula should work:

`=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(f4), ISNUMBER(i4)), i4+f4+1, 0)`

PS: you don't say what happens if neither f4 nor i4 have a number.  I'm assuming the same as if only one of the cells have a number.

Comment: This works too and with reduced code! Thank you! I'm learning all kinds of great stuff today. Awesome.